# PWA notification grouping

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA and implemented push notifications. 
From what I understand notifications can be replaced using `tag` and behaviour controlled using `renotify`. [Google documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/notification-behaviour)

This may be a good way to keep down the amount of displayed notifications, but is there a way to group notifications in a PWA?

In native apps I have noticed that notifications get "grouped" or "stacked" into one notification if there are more than a certain amount of notifications. Can this be achieved in a PWA?

Code for showing a push notification:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event){
  console.log('Push Notification received', event)
  const defaultData = {title: 'New!', content: 'Something new happened!', openUrl: '/'}
  const data = (event.data) ? JSON.parse(event.data.text()) : defaultData

  var options = {
    body: data.content,
    icon: '/img/ico/manifest-512.png', 
    badge: '/img/ico/badge96.png', 
    // tag: 'myTag', 
    // renotify: true,
    data: {
      url: data.openUrl
    }
  }

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options)
  )
})
```

Kind regards /K

Comment: Is is not at [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/common-notification-patterns#merging_notifications) within the website you provided?

Comment: Thanks Matt! It seems to be exactly what I have been looking for. Many thanks! /K